# "leads back in the time of" or "leads back to the time of"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is it correct to say "leads back ***in*** the time of Reunification" or "leads back ***to*** the time of Reunification"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"leads back to the time of" is correct.

For example:

> This line of study leads [us] back to the time of reunification.

However, I think you might be better of using "dates back to" instead.

> This custom dates back to the time of reunification.

Although without any further context, it is hard to tell.

---

Also, there is no need to capitalize reunification.